# Elasticsearch using Java api

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Hi I am trying to do query on elastic search by following the sql query and I want to implement same logic using Java API

```
select * from log , web where l.loghost = w.webhost and @datetime between '2016-05-20' AND '2016-05-25'
```

`log` and `web` are different types, and indices are set to `logstash-log-*` and `logstash-web*`, `@timestamp` format looks like `"2016-05-20T17:14:01.037Z"`

Now I have the following Java code but i don't know how to set  between two dates ,so it does not return expected output

```
  SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("logstash-log-*","logstash-web-*")
   .setTypes("log","web")
  .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
  .setFetchSource(new String[]{"*"}, null)
 .setQuery(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("1.2.3.4").field("*_host"))// Query
  .execute()
 .actionGet();
```

Please guide I am new to Elastic search. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to combine a [`range` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-term-level-queries.html#java-query-dsl-range-query) with your `query_string` query inside a [`bool/filter` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-compound-queries.html#java-query-dsl-bool-query):

```
QueryStringQueryBuilder qs = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("1.2.3.4").field("*_host");
RangeQueryBuilder range = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("@timestamp")
    .gte("2016-05-20T00:00:00.000Z")
    .lte("2016-05-25T00:00:00.000Z");
```

and then

```
...
.setQuery(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().filter(qs).filter(range))
...
```

Comment: from "RangeQueryBuilder range = QueryBuilders.rangeQ......"  , i got the error msg "Type mismatch: cannot convert from org.elasticsearch.index.query.RangeQueryBuilder to org.apache.lucene.queryparser.xml.builders.RangeQueryBuilder"

Comment: The correct import to use is `import org.elasticsearch.index.query.RangeQueryBuilder;` not `import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.xml.builders.RangeQueryBuilder;`

Comment: What import statement do you have for `QueryBuilders`?

Comment: I don't get what your problem is. Please explain thoroughly so we can help. Besides, you should not create an answer for that, simply update your question with additional info.